# Web oriented language: C-like syntax, strong and static typing. Anyone?

Tags: php, c

I have been using PHP 5+ for quite a while now.

I am looking at an alternative because I would like to learn something new and I feel like PHP is *kind of mess*, even though I do like it for its ease of deployment/use.

This alternative should:

- have a **C-like syntax**
- have **strong and static typing**
- be **compatible** with Linux and open source webservers such as Nginx/Apache

Comment: Well, you can write a web application even in Verilog.. so what is your question exactly?

Comment: C#! It's theoretically compatible, but you'd have to write your own Apache module :) Seriously: You can run it on Linux using Mono, and it suits your needs perfectly. It's just not open-source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "Play!" framework, it uses Java / Scala to program.

HomePage: [Playframework](http://www.playframework.org/)

Comment: Java is probably the closest you'll get without resorting to something that no one actually uses.